# How to correctly count allocated memory

Tags: java, rounding

I have that task:

> Assume that in addition to the scaling factor, there is a factor responsible for deallocating unnecessary memory after removing elements from the list. You will be given two factors: one for increasing and one for reducing the allocated memory. Following that will be queries for abstract addition and removal of clusters of elements.
>   Your task is to return the allocated memory for each 'count' query at that moment.
>
> Multiplication on a fraction is rounded up, division by a fraction is rounded down.
>
> The initially allocated memory is 2.
>
> Input: In the first line there's a number of queries and both the scaling (≥1.1) and downscaling (≥1.1) factors.
>
> Following that are queries of these types: add count; remove count; count.
>
> Output: For every 'count' query, write down the amount of allocated memory at the moment.

**Input 1:**

3 2.0 2.0

add 100

delete 50

count

**Output 1:**

64

**Input 2:**

12 1.1 1.1

add 10000

delete 500

count

add 255342

delete 255

count

add 243

delete 2435

count

add 666554

delete 346

count

Unfortunatelly, I don't know what output should be for test2.
My code works correctly with test1, but it gets failed with test2.
Can anyone help me? Maybe problem with rounding, may be not.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        int queryNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        double upScalingFactor = scanner.nextDouble();
        double downScalingFactor = scanner.nextDouble();

        int allocatedMemory = 2;
        int numOfElementsToStore = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < queryNumber; i++) {
            String operationType = scanner.next();

            switch (operationType) {
                case "add":
                    int amountToAdd = scanner.nextInt();
                    numOfElementsToStore += amountToAdd;

                    while (allocatedMemory <= numOfElementsToStore) {
                        allocatedMemory = (int) Math.ceil(allocatedMemory * upScalingFactor);
                    }
                    break;
                case "delete":
                    int amountToSubtract = scanner.nextInt();
                    numOfElementsToStore -= amountToSubtract;

                    while (Math.floor(allocatedMemory / downScalingFactor) >= numOfElementsToStore) {
                        allocatedMemory = (int) Math.floor(allocatedMemory / downScalingFactor);
                    }
                    break;
                case "count":
                    System.out.println(allocatedMemory);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not cast multiply/divide the result inside while loop. And always use `Math.floor()`.

Correct **output** for **input 2**:

```
9660
271469
271469
937184
```